# Multiple git accounts, wrong git account is pushing to my personal repo

Tags: git, github, git-commit, multiple-accounts

I'm trying to do a personal project. I haven't used git much except for work which I got working a while ago. I'm trying to push an initial commit to a personal repo but I keep getting:

> Permission to personalAcc/project.git denied to workAcc

I have tried the steps that are taken here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ but I still get the same errors. Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your `user.email` set correctly?

`git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL"`

This email address should match one of the [addresses in GitHub settings](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/) of the account you're trying to push with.

Comment: The email that is printed out is my personal email but it is still denying access to my work account. The work account is done with isn't done with my personal email obviously.

Comment: Look into github settings of your work account on github.com . Find the email address you registered this account with and then set it into git configuration by `git config --global user.email "YOUR_WORK_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"`